# Cannot get response from WebAPI

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api, cors

UPDATE : Now I have better understanding of the error. I am facing the error explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/3021830. This is now what I should fix.

I have REST API created with ASP.NET WebAPI. It is hosted on http://localhost:54700/. I also have a GET method with route "api/RefData", so basically I need to call http://localhost:54700/api/RefData. IT is also marked with `AllowAnonymous` attribute

When I make a GET call from PostMan everything seems to work fine.
But I try to call it from my ASP.NET MVC application, both from server and client I can not get any result.

My server side code is :

```
private static HttpClient _client;
private static HttpClient Client
{
    get
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54700/");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        }
        return _client;
    }
}


internal List<HeardAbout> HeardAbouts
{
    get
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["refData"] == null)
        {
            GetRefData().Wait();
        }
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["refData"] as List<RefData>;
    }
}

private async Task<List<RefData>> GetRefData()
{
    try
    {
        List<RefData> has = new List<RefData>();
        // The following line is where the code leaves debugging
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync("api/RefData");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            has = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<RefData>>();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["refData"] = has;
        }
        return has;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

and my client side code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:54700/api/RefData",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        if (callback)
            callback(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        if (callback)
            error(response.d);
    },
});
```

The server-side codes reaches the commented line. Then leaves debugging. I wrapped the code with `try-catch` block but it does not raise an exception as well.

The client-side code falls to error with statusText "error".

What is wrong with these codes and how may I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the status code returned in your server side httpclient?

Comment: In the client side code try method: 'GET' instead of type

Comment: It does not make sense but as far as I can see response.statusCode returns function (e){var t;if(e)if(2>b)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else C.always(e[C.status]);return this}

Comment: I think I got where I screwed up. My WebAPI and my site is running on different domain and I am getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:55973' is therefore not allowed access." error. I think this is what I need to fix.

Comment: look for CORS, i had similar issue and enabled cors and worked.

Answer (score 1):

As I have denoted in the update the calls were failed because the domain addresses of my web application and WebAPI were different.

To solve the problem I have used information provided here : [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). And now it works.

Comment: I did this on my issue (similiar to this one related) and worked.